# List Comprehension Library for Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, common-lisp, list-comprehension

I know there is a list-comprehension library for common lisp ([incf-cl](http://superadditive.com/projects/incf-cl/)), I know they're supported natively in various other functional (and some non-functional) languages (F#, Erlang, Haskell and C#) - is there a list comprehension library for Scheme?

incf-cl is implemented in CL as a library using macros - shouldn't it be possible to use the same techniques to create one for Scheme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Swindle](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/swindle/index.html) is primarily a CLOS emulator library, but it has list comprehensions too. I've used them, they're convenient, but the version I used was buggy and incomplete. (I just needed generic functions.)
- However, you probably want [SRFI-42](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-42/srfi-42.html). I haven't used it, but it HAS to have fewer bugs than the Swindle list comprehensions.

I don't know which Scheme you use. [PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org) bundles Swindle and SRFI-42. Both are supposed to be cross-Scheme compatible, though.

If you use PLT Scheme, here is SRFI-42's [man page](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/srfi/srfi-42.html). You say `(require srfi/42)` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ for R6RS Scheme](https://ironscheme.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronScheme/IronSchemeConsole/ironscheme/linq.ss) (although it could be made to run under 'older' implementations).